# How to get dummies of only those values that occur more than X time in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using this to get dummies
`train = pd.get_dummies(train, columns=['LSOA code','Last outcome category','Month'])`

But I want to get dummies of only those whose value repeat more than 1000 times

Sample DF:

```
id     col1
1      aaa
2      aaa
3      aaa
4      bbb
5      bbb
6      ccc
```

Current output using this code : `df= pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['col1'])`

```
id     aaa   bbb   ccc
1      1     0      0
2      1     0      0
3      1     0      0
4      0     1      0
5      0     1      0
6      0     0      0
```

What I want: Get dummies of only those value that repeat more than once

```
id     aaa   bbb   
1      1     0     
2      1     0      
3      1     0      
4      0     1      
5      0     1      
6      0     0
```

Comment: please create a small sample data and expected output. Thanks

Comment: Done @anky_91 .

Comment: No, i have categorical columns and I want to convert  them using one hot encoding. But I do not want to convert for all values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try creating a list of "valid" categories using [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and your logical condition `> 1000`.

Then call [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) on [`pandas.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) type, with this list of valid `categories` passed as an argument:

```
cats = df['col1'].value_counts()[lambda x: x > 1000].index

pd.get_dummies(pd.Categorical(df['col1'], categories=cats))
```

#### Using your example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6}, 'col1': {0: 'aaa', 1: 'aaa', 2: 'aaa', 3: 'bbb', 4: 'bbb', 5: 'ccc'}})

cats = df['col1'].value_counts()[lambda x: x > 1].index

pd.get_dummies(pd.Categorical(df['col1'], categories=cats))
```

[out]

```
   aaa  bbb
0    1    0
1    1    0
2    1    0
3    0    1
4    0    1
5    0    0
```